# Can I replace Array with constant?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using VBA in Excel to make query and I want replace the

```
St" _
            ), Array( _
            "efl\zv162_part1.xls
```

with constant **part1**

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=\\St" _
        ), Array( _
        "efl\zv162_part1.xls;DefaultDir=cesta;DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
        )), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT `zv162_part1$`.F2, `zv162_part1$`.F4, `zv162_part1$`.F5, `zv162_part1$`.F6, `zv162_pa" _
        , _
        "rt1$`.F7, `zv162_part1$`.F8, `zv162_part1$`.F9, `zv162_part1$`.F10, `zv162_part1$`.F11, `zv162_part1$`.F12, `zv162_part1$`.F13, `zv162_part1$`.F14, `zv162_part1$`.F15, `zv162_part1$`.F16, `z" _
        , _
        "v162_part1$`.F17, `zv162_part1$`.F18, `zv162_part1$`.F19, `zv162_part1$`.F20" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `zv162_part1$` `zv162_part1$`" & "WHERE `zv162_part1$`.F2 <> Null" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Excel_Files13"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


    End With
```

Thank you for any response!

I add whole command for query

Comment: Can you type the complete string so that I can test it? The part before `St" _` The reason being `)` before `, Array` is kind of confusing me....

Comment: i was using macro recorder for make it

Comment: Can you paste the complete line?

Comment: At `DefaultDir`  i have constant **cesta** here

Comment: basically you want a variable for `efl\zv162_part1.xls`

Comment: no its whole `stefl\zv162_part1.xls` the array is making problem for me..

Comment: Try this for me...  `With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, _
              Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & part1 & ";DefaultDir=" & cesta & ";DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;") _
              ), _
              Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
              ).QueryTable` where part1 = "\\Stefl\zv162_part1.xls"

Comment: enter a newline after every ` _` manually.

Comment: I got error **Type mismatch**

Comment: Did you try this? http://wikisend.com/download/114368/1.png

Comment: yes and I've got type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
part1 = "stefl\zv162_part1.xls"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
   SourceType:=0, _
   Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & _
   part1 & _
   ";DefaultDir=cesta;DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;") _
   ), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```